# Expected Value of given two parameters

Tags: matlab

I would like to know how to compute:

E[Y | X_i, X_j]

on MATLAB.

Let's say

x = unifrnd(0,1,1000,2) and the model is y = x1 + x2.

suppose that you have scatter plot x1 vs Y and x2 vs Y. With these scatter plots, you compute the regression coefficient (i.e. f1 = ax1 + b and f2 = cx2 + d).

now I want to compute expected value of Y given x1 and x2.

My question is how do I do that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Obviously `E[Y|X1,X2] = E[X1+X2|X1,X2] = X1+X2`